# How do i implement search on third level using containable behavior

Tags: search, jqgrid, cakephp-1.3, containable

I have developed a cake php application.

In this there are tables like students,placements,batches,companies

In placements table there is student_id,company_id and in students table there is batch_id column.

In placements index page i have applied jq grid. Here is the screen shot.
[image]

I want to give searching on student,company and batch. For this i have used containable behavior inside placements controller index function.

```
            if( $this->params['url']['_search'] == 'true' ) /* For Searching*/
        {
            //pr($this->params);

            $searchconditions = array();

            if( isset($this->params['url']['studentname']) && !empty($this->params['url']['studentname']) )
            {
                array_push(&$searchconditions, array('Student.fullname LIKE' => $this->params['url']['studentname'] . '%'));
            }
             if( isset($this->params['url']['companyname']) && !empty($this->params['url']['companyname']) )
            {
                array_push(&$searchconditions, array('Company.name LIKE' => $this->params['url']['companyname'] . '%'));
            }
             if( isset($this->params['url']['batchname']) && !empty($this->params['url']['batchname']) )
            {
                array_push(&$searchconditions, array('Batch.name LIKE' => $this->params['url']['batchname'] . '%'));
            }

            $result = $this->Placement->find('all', array(
                'fields' => array('id','student_id','company_id'),
                'contain' => array(
                    'Student' => array(
                        'fields' => array('id','fullname','batch_id'),
                        'Batch' => array(
                            'fields'=> array('id','name')
                        )       
                    ),
                    'Company' => array(
                        'fields' => array('id','name')
                    )
                ),
                'conditions' => $searchconditions,
                'order' => $sort_range,
                'limit' => $limit_range
            ));
        }
        else /* Default display*/
        {
            $result = $this->Placement->find('all', array(
                'fields' => array('id','student_id','company_id'),
                'contain' => array(
                    'Student' => array(
                        'fields' => array('id','fullname','batch_id'),
                        'Batch' => array(
                            'fields'=> array('id','name')
                        )       
                    ),
                    'Company' => array(
                        'fields' => array('id','name')
                    )
                ),
                'order' => $sort_range,
                'limit' => $limit_range
            ));
        }
```

The grid is populated fine with student name , company name and batch name (if case).
Searching is also working fine in case i searched by student name & company name but when i tried to search by batch name i get the  following error:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Batch.name' in 'where clause' [APP\vendors\cakephp\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 681]

Query: SELECT `Placement`.`id`, `Placement`.`student_id`, `Placement`.`company_id`, `Student`.`id`, `Student`.`fullname`, `Student`.`batch_id`, `Company`.`id`, `Company`.`name` FROM `placements` AS `Placement` LEFT JOIN `students` AS `Student` ON (`Placement`.`student_id` = `Student`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `companies` AS `Company` ON (`Placement`.`company_id` = `Company`.`id`)  WHERE `Batch`.`name` LIKE 'df%'   ORDER BY `Placement`.`id` asc  LIMIT 0,10
```

I think the relation between student & batch is not working as can be seen from the query.

I am unable to figure out why it is behaving as such.

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Containable behavior doesn't make a join, but makes separate queries for each table.
Use the **[linkable plugin](http://github.com/Terr/linkable)**. It's an excellent plugin. It will definitely solve your problem.

Answer posted by **Mr. [sytzeloor](http://cakeqs.org/eng/users/view/sytzeloor)** on [cakeqs](http://cakeqs.org) site.

Using this plugin you will be able to easily do a find operation in the placement model based on a batch name.

Do like this in your placements controller and I bet you will get results as expected.

```
$result = $this->Placement->find('all', array(
                'fields' => array('id','student_id','company_id'),
                'link' => array(
                    'Student' => array(
                        'Batch'
                    ),
                    'Company'
                ),
                'conditions' => $searchconditions,
                'order' => $sort_range,
                'limit' => $limit_range
            ));
```